# Only validate text field when display=block

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate my form, but ONLY if its surrounding div is being displayed at the time.
This is what I have so far:

```
function validateForm()
 {
 var x=document.forms["config"]["itemname5"].value;
if (document.getElementById("customtext").style.display=="block" || x==null)
   {
   alert("Text box must be filled in");
   return false;
   }
 }
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<div class="hide" id="customtext">Enter the text you require on the module. eg. "DAVE" max 6 letters<br />
<input type=text name="itemname5"  class="nicebox" value='' maxlength="6" style="font-size:14; font-weight:bold; width:210px; vertical-align:top; height:20px;">
</div>
```

I want it so that if the div is displayed, it will tell the user if they haven't entered any text and won't post the form.

Here's the page: http://www.censdigital.com/2012/earplugs-config.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, we know what the expected behavior is.  What behavior do you get with your current code?

Comment: I want it so that if the div is displayed, it will tell the user if they haven't entered any text and wont post the form.

Comment: Unless you are specifically setting items as `display = "block"` I would change your `if` statement to `element.style.display != "none"` this will then also handle the element being visible but the display property not being set or being blank.

Comment: @MarkWalters I bet that's the answer. Great idea. I don't do these types of comparisons (I use Parthik Gosar's answer), but I wouldn't have thought of that when the `display` isn't set :)

Comment: Thanks Mark.. that seems to work if I change the != too == but it is still posting the form and going to basket page after the popup!

Comment: @user2215938 I think Mark is suggesting that you use `if (document.getElementById("customtext").style.display !== "none" || x==null) {`

Comment: @Ian Yes, thank you Ian that is what I did do, but now the form is still posting after the popup comes up and going to the next page!

Comment: @alan please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Your logic could fail incase when the parent of the customText div is hidden. If you need to handle such a case, it would be very simple through jquery.

You can simple check if an element is visible through

```
$(x).is(":visible") /*returns true or false*/
```

edit:

To use jQUery, add this to the head section of your page, you can also download this js file and host it locally.

Once this is added, you can check if the your element x is visible by

```
if($(x).is(":visible"))
{
  //your element is visible
}
```

I would recommend reading up more on jQuery which is a very powerful library. And will help you a lot. www.jquery.com

Comment: Very true point about parents being hidden, but where does the OP say they use jQuery?

Comment: Thanks, but I am very new to jQuery and Java, where would I put your code for it to work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement only accounts for when the elements `display` property is set to `"block"` there are many other states in which the element is visible. I would test on whether it is not hidden, like this

```
if (document.getElementById("customtext").style.display != "none" && x==""){
   alert("Text box must be filled in"); 
   return false;
}
```

Now if the `display` property is not set or not set to `"block"` you will still get the expected results.

Your issue with the form still submitting is probably to do with how your running your function. Can you show me where the function is called from. It looks like your `return false` statement is just exiting your function rather than preventing the form from submitting.

Comment: I don't want to add an answer because you were the one that found the main problem, but I think the condition you want is `if (document.getElementById("customtext").style.display !== "none" && x === "") {`. Which is saying "if the parent is visible AND the textbox's value is empty, then display the error". Notice that the `||` becomes `&&`, and the `null` becomes `""`. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BRdGP/ . You're welcome to use any of this in your answer. **EDIT:** Wait, I lied...it's not working. Haha hold on

Comment: @Ian you're right about the logic, the `||` doesn't work. i've updated my answer

Comment: Right, and the logic makes sense, but the problem is with `.style.display`. If you look at my fiddle and see how the element has a `hide` class. That class is the one that specifies `display: none;` (which is what I'm guessing the OP's code is like). But the result of `.style.display` for the element is always `""`. Which is not what I expected, but I guess that makes sense. So the first part of the `if` statement will always be true when using classes to hide an element. Obviously, if `.style.display` was explicitly set to something, the value would be reflected...but the OP is using a class